# Downcasting in Java throws ClassCastException

Tags: java, casting, downcast

I don't understand why the casting from bellow doesn't work ( `Helicopter h = (Helicopter) new Rotorcraft();`) and `throws` a `Runtime exception` of type `ClassCastException`.

Base class:

```
public  class Rotorcraft {

protected final int height = 5;
    protected int fly(){
        return height;
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class Helicopter extends Rotorcraft {    
    private int height = 10;

    public int fly() {
        return super.height;
    }

    public static final void main(String[] a){
        Helicopter h = (Helicopter) new Rotorcraft();
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Rotorcraft` is **not** always a `Helicopter`

Comment: True but if I'm saying: trust me and and run the code, however it fails at run time. After casting I want to run the method fly on Helicopter reference.

Comment: @SocketM "Trust me" the compiler did. And you didn't give it an instance of `Helicopter`, so the cast fails.

Comment: You have it wrong in your mind. as you wrote you are saying that a helicopter is a rotocraft and thats why you are getting the error. instead, Rotocraft should extend Helicopter class. then the 'Helicopter h = (Helicopter) new Rotorcraft();' will work

Comment: Why am I wrong, if I have the fly method in parent and subclass? This is not polymorphic behavior ?

Comment: @SocketM a reference of type `Rotorcraft` can point to a `Helicopter` (or null), which is why you are allowed to do the cast. But if it points to a `Rotorcraft`, not a `Helicopter`, you can't simply pretend that it *is* a `Helicopter`, because `Helicopter` might (now or in the future) have methods amd fields not present on a `Rotorcraft`. If you want to make use of polymorphic behaviour, use it as a `Rotorcraft`.

Comment: So basically when you do Rotorcraft r = new Helicopter() will always work becuase Helicopter object inherits from Rotorcraft. When we use a Rotorcraft reference for a Helicopter object we are using a subset of instance methods and fields available in Helicopter object. Vice versa when we try to use a Helicopter reference on Rotorcraft object we will get a ClassCasting exception due to the fact that Rotorcraft object is not an Helicopter. Rotorcraft object dosen't have all methods / instance fields that an Helicopter has or could have in the future. I got it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic issue is that you're trying to convert into a `Helicopter` something that isn't (it's a `Rotorcraft`). A cast cannot change the runtime class of an object.

Did you mean to simply write:

```
Helicopter h = new Helicopter();
```

?

Comment: Helicopter h = new Helicopter() will always work. I'm trying some polymorphic behavior :-)

Comment: @SocketM: Polymorphism doesn't work like that (not in Java, anyway). You can't create an instance of a base class and then somehow pretend that it's an instance of a derived class. It isn't, and a cast won't make it so.

Comment: Thank you @NPE. Can you please check my assumption added on comments section attached to my question